Second-Order Latent Variable in SEM
I am planning to examine the effect of instructional quality on well-being using SEM. Well-being is conceptualized as consisting of five dimensions, with the possibility of calculating a general factor as well. My hypotheses pertain to both specific dimensions and the general factor.
Confirmatory Factor Analysis (CFA) indicates that both a five-factor model and a second-order factor model, with orthogonal first-order factors, fit the data well. Would it be appropriate to conduct two separate SEM analyses: one with the five-factor model as the outcome and the other with the second-order model? This approach would enable me to test my hypotheses related to both the specific factors and the general factor.
As I am relatively new to SEM, I would greatly appreciate your feedback on my research design.

If I've understood correctly, these models seem to be nested within a larger model.
In the larger model, you have a second order factor model, where both the second order factor AND the five first order factors predict well-being. This model is saturated in the causal part that you are interested in.
You can then compare this model to two models, using a chi-square difference test: The model with only the second order factor predicting well-being, and the model with only the five first order models predicting well-being.
You can also compare these models using fit measures such as AIC and BIC.
